# Mapping a dot over an image

Tags: html, css, image

I have this gif image, but i want to place a dot on 261,274 on that image. The dot is 7px by 7px. How can i do this? I have tried this:

```
<table style="background: url('mainimage.gif'); width:513px; height:550px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative; top:274px; left:-261px; background: url('dot.gif'); width:7px; height:7px;"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

And this:

```
<div style="background: url('mainimage.gif'); width:513px; height:550px;">
    <div style="position:relative; top:274px; left:-261px; background: url('dot.gif'); width:7px; height:7px;"></div>
</div>
```

But those doesn't seem to work properly.

I have also looked at the area element, but i can't realy figure out how to work with those.

EDIT: Jsfiddle's:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ahfd/
http://jsfiddle.net/3Ahfd/1/

Comment: could you please create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative positionioning. There you go:

```
<div style="background: url('mainimage.gif'); width:550px; height:513px; position: relative;">
    <img src="dot.gif" style="position: relative; top:264px; left:258px; width:7px; height:7px;">
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/3Ahfd/6/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div style="background: url('mainimage.gif'); width:513px; height:550px;position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:271px; left:259px; background: url('dot.gif'); width:7px; height:7px;"></div>
</div>
```

Note: adjust top and left of the inner div accordingly - I subtracted 3px from your coordinates to center the dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="background: url('mainimage.gif'); width:513px; height:550px; position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:274px; left:261px; background: url('dot.gif'); width:7px; height:7px;"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ahfd/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the dot a background image of a `div`, I'd suggest just using it as an `image` tag and positioning it accordingly using margins.

Something like:

```
<div style="background: url('mainimage.gif'); width:513px; height:550px;">
    <img src="dot.gif" style="margin-top:274px; margin-left:-261px;" />
</div>
```